# SQL query, MAX date, group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help me with a sql query? I'm looking for the most recent date (datum). It has the same OBJID but not the same RADOMGID.

```
BESADR  ARSMEDEL    METOD   DATUM       FNR         BYGGID  OBJID   RADOMGID

bladv   410         spar    20040930    40014686    1       14778   13640

bladv   340         m       19860505    40014686    1       14778   1026
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you add your table structure? and the query you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, with `MAX` to find each OBJID's max datum:

```
select OBJID, max(DATUM)
from tablename
group by OBJID
```

If you want the whole row (with max datum), use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude older rows:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.OBJID = t1.OBJID
                    and t2.datum > t1.datum)
```

Will return both rows if there's a tie.

Comment: Thanks! But can I make a query where I can get all the other columns too at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

all newest rows for every `RADOMGID`

```
select t1.* from yourtable t1
join (
   select radomgid, max(Datum)
   from yourtable t2
   group by radomgid
     ) on t1.radomgid = t2.radomgid
```

Comment: I suggest select t1.*, and datum in join condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the latest, assuming the table is called my_object_list

```
select BESADR, ARSMEDEL, METOD, max(DATUM) DATUM, 
       FNR, BYGGID, OBJID, RADOMGID
from my_object_list mol
Where Objid = '14778'
group by BESADR, ARSMEDEL, METOD, 
       FNR, BYGGID, OBJID, RADOMGID
having max(datum) = mol.datum;
```